# Confusion about pm2 restart vs reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

Issuing "pm2 restart all" will restart all of the processes pm2 is managing.

I am wondering:  If there have been changes to any of the source files, does this actually reload the changes?  Or does it just restart the existing pm2 process in memory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `pm2 restart` picks up local changes. Clients may have to clear cache/refresh if you're not seeing the changes.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what the difference between the two as stated in title.
`pm2 reload all` vs `pm2 restart all`.

Comment: > Yes, pm2 restart picks up local changes.

It's worth noting that `pm2 restart` will _not_ pick up any changes to the pm2.yml or pm2.json file itself though.  This has killed me several times. If your pm2.yml or pm2.json has changed you have to do a `pm2 stop && pm2 delete && pm2 start`.

Comment: @shriek answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883269/what-is-the-difference-between-pm2-restart-and-pm2-reload