# What is the difference between pm2 restart and pm2 reload

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a nodejs app running on server.

When should I use **pm2 restart**,and when should **pm2 reload** be used?

Referred to the [pm2 documention](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#reloading-without-downtime) here,but couldn't figure out the difference in use case of the two.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The difference is documented [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#reload):

> As opposed to `restart`, which kills and restarts the process, `reload` achieves a 0-second-downtime reload.

The latter means (found [here](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/load-balancing/#0-seconds-downtime-reload)):

> With reload, `pm2` restarts all processes one by one, always keeping at least one process running.

It also states that:

> If the reload system hasn’t managed to reload your application, a timeout will fallback to a classic restart.

Comment: So restart first kills then starts whereas reload first starts then kills?

Comment: @Cristy I'd think so, yes. I also assume that if it can't restart a worker, `reload` will keep the old worker running, so it wouldn't be noticable.

Comment: @robertklep So why should restart be used at all?Is there any use case where restart can be more beneficial than reload?

Comment: @Ayan perhaps `restart` is faster, and if you don't care about 0-second downtime it might be preferable.

Comment: From the documentation, `reload` should be used always with [stateless applications](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/load-balancing/#stateless-application). It is also documented now that `reload` will fallback to `restart` after a timeout.

Comment: Conclusion: always use `reload`!

Comment: The 2nd link has changed to https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/load-balancing/

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira not really: always use it **if** you are in cluster mode and your app is stateless. If you are not in cluster mode then both commands are the same, and if you are but your application is stateful then `reload` will break it so you must use `restart`.